# AJAX/jQuery alert() works, .html() or .text() doesn't

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm newbie to jquery and AJAX and I have a really annoying problem with returning AJAX response simply into a `div`.

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "lists2.php",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#sidebar-content").text("Loading..");
        },
        complete: function() {
            $("#sidebar-content").text("");
        },
        success: function(lists) {
            $("#sidebar-content").text(lists);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Something went wrong..");
        }
    });
});
```

Code fires fine and no error appears, Firebug shows also no errors and if I put **for example** `alert(lists)` instead of `.text()` or `.html()` it works and alerts the data. But `.text()` or `.html()` don't work.

`lists2.php` is a complex file that analyzes data from `SQL db` and outputs the content inside a bootstrap sidebar. It worked fine in the old version without AJAX.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show your html mark up

Comment: comment the complete: function(){} it will work, as you are getting lists in success and clearing the lists in complete function..

Comment: Of course, how dumb I am.. now it works! Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Ropkeit You could always accept my answer if it helped. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Complete()` fires after `success()`, and is clearing your content.

> **Complete**
>
> A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error
>   callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The
>   jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string
>   categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified",
>   "nocontent", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror"). As of
>   jQuery 1.5, the complete setting can accept an array of functions.
>   Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/